# How to undelete an improved answer that was improved?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

More than 5 years ago I gave a quick link only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953360/can-adobe-air-desktop-application-take-full-screen-snapshots-aka-print-screen-b/2992142#2992142).

Since then things have changed.

Stackoverflow now clearly explains how some answers get deleted including my case("barely more than a link to an external site").

I am aware of how to provide better, more helpful answers and I strive to do so. Even though the answer in it's form might have helped at that time, a more detailed answer with an updated link will keep it relevant for longer.

Unfortunately now this answer is in the situation where it has been flagged and I hadn't had a chance to update it. I agree with the fact that based on current SO standards and best practices the answer wasn't helping as much, but I don't believe it's fair to not get a chance to fix my mistake.

The question went from flagged to deleted within ~40 minutes.

What can I do to undelete a an updated answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the answer was deleted from review, you can undelete it yourself. Moderators get an automatic system flag for events like that where we can check and see if the answer was indeed improved.

When an answer was deleted by a moderator, you'll have to flag for it to be undeleted. A custom flag explaining how you've expanded the answer beyond a simple link (which I think was also dead, in this case) should be enough for us to act on.

As you've pointed the link to an archived copy of the site and added the key code in the answer itself, I've undeleted this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and undelete Brad.